# Call to a member function num_rows() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-3

When visiting the page an error occurs and is shown on the page. The error that gets shown is described below:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on bool

Filename: localhost/app/models/admin/Reports_model.php
```

The method that is referenced in the error is as such:

```
public function getTotalReturnSales($start, $end, $warehouse_id = null)
    {
        $this->db->select('count(id) as total, sum(COALESCE(grand_total, 0)) as total_amount, SUM(COALESCE(paid, 0)) as paid, SUM(COALESCE(total_tax, 0)) as tax', false)
            ->where('date BETWEEN ' . $start . ' and ' . $end);
        if ($warehouse_id) {
            $this->db->where('warehouse_id', $warehouse_id);
        }
        $q = $this->db->get('returns');
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->row();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How could this error be caused?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->get()` will return `false` if the query fails. As you know, `false` is a boolean and has no "methods". If you run the following

```
$q = $this->db->get('returns');
var_dump($q)
```

It will almost certainly tell you `$q` is a bool with a value of false.

The most common reason for a failed query is faulty sql statement syntax. One way to see the query statement that Query Builder created is by putting the following two lines before `$q = $this->db->get('returns');`

```
$sql = $this->db->get_compiled_select('returns', false); 
var_dump($sql);
```

You might be able to see what is causing the problem.

Note: A query that returns no rows is not a failure.