# Codeigniter 3 - Call to a member function num_rows() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have this Codeigniter3 query.

```
$this->db->select("COUNT(city) AS totals");
$this->db->from('contacts');
$this->db->group_by('totals'); 
$this->db->order_by('totals', 'DESC'); 
            
$query =  $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

After moving the application to a server with mysql 5.7+ I get this error:

```
Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on bool
```

I know that can solve adding ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

But is there a way to solve it by code?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640001/call-to-a-member-function-num-rows-on-bool?

Comment: Yes already checked others topic about this, but I can't resolve. This topic explain only way for read generated query by builder, but query is correct.

Comment: how about wrapping it with ANY_VALUE()

Comment: chect this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Your query is **incorrect** as you are trying to group on the alias that represents the count calculated field. You either need to specify an existing other field in the group by or if you just want to get a single count number, then you do not need the group by clause.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. Please try below method,

```
 $this->db->select('city_id, COUNT(city_id) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('city_id'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $this->db->get('tablename', 10);
```